# How to modify contents of a pipe-delimited text file with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a pipe-delimited text file.  The file contains "records" of various types.  I want to modify certain columns for each record type.  For simplicity, let's say there are 3 record types: A, B, and C.  A has 3 columns, B has 4 columns, and C has 5 columns.  For example, we have:

```
A|stuff|more_stuff
B|123|other|x
C|something|456|stuff|more_stuff
B|78903|stuff|x
A|1|more_stuff
```

I want to append the prefix "P" to all desired columns.  For A, the desired column is 2.  For B, the desired column is 3.  For C, the desired column is 4.

So, I want the output to look like:

```
A|Pstuff|more_stuff
B|123|Pother|x
C|something|456|Pstuff|more_stuff
B|78903|Pstuff|x
A|P1|more_stuff
```

I need to do this in PowerShell.  The file could be very large.  So, I'm thinking about going with the File-class of .NET.  If it were a simple string replacement, I would do something like:

```
$content = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("H:\test_modify_contents.txt").Replace("replace_text","something_else")
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText("H:\output_file.txt", $content)
```

But, it's not so simple in my particular situation.  So, I'm not even sure if ReadAllText and WriteAllText is the best solution.  Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would `ConvertFrom-Csv` so you can check each line as an object. On this code, I did add a header, but mainly for code readability. The header is cut out of the output on the last line anyway:

```
$input = "H:\test_modify_contents.txt"
$output = "H:\output_file.txt"
$data = Get-Content -Path $input | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter '|' -Header 'Column1','Column2','Column3','Column4','Column5'

$data | % {
   If ($_.Column5) {
      #type C:
      $_.Column4 = "P$($_.Column4)"
   } ElseIf ($_.Column4) {
      #type B:
      $_.Column3 = "P$($_.Column3)"
   } Else {
      #type A:
      $_.Column2 = "P$($_.Column2)"
   }
}

$data | Select Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5 | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter '|' -NoTypeInformation | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Set-Content -Path $output
```

It does add extra `|` for the type A and B lines. Output:

```
"A"|"Pstuff"|"more_stuff"||
"B"|"123"|"Pother"|"x"|
"C"|"something"|"456"|"Pstuff"|"more_stuff"
"B"|"78903"|"Pstuff"|"x"|
"A"|"P1"|"more_stuff"||
```

Comment: The conditionals don't make sense to me.  What does ($.Column5) achieve?  Shouldn't it be ($.Column1 -eq "C")?

Comment: `if ($_.Column5)` will just test if it exists, because if it does... it's type C. Your condition would also work though.

Comment: Is there a clean way to remove the quotation marks and the extra pipe characters that get added to record types A and B?

Comment: Instead of changing the values to add P, those lines could each be changed to output directly. For example, type A lines: `Add-Content -Path $output "$($_.Column1)|P$($_.Column2)|$($_.Column3)`n" `. There is no need for that last line at all then. This will probably be slow, I would have to generate a large file to test.

Comment: I just tested your solution on a 1.1 [MB] file, and it takes about 4 minutes to finish.  My actual files will most likely be much bigger.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: This one should not have been marked as the right answer? Look at Dave Sexton's  answer with the latest edit. It looks promising i think.

Answer (score 1):

If your file sizes are large then reading the complete file contents at once using Import-Csv or ReadAll is probably not a good idea. I would use Get-Content cmdlet using the ReadCount property which will stream the file one row at time and then use a regex for the processing. Something like this:

```
Get-Content your_in_file.txt -ReadCount 1 | % {
  $_ -replace '^(A\||B\|[^\|]+\||C\|[^\|]+\|[^\|]+\|)(.*)$', '$1P$2'
} | Set-Content your_out_file.txt
```

**EDIT:**
This version should output faster:

```
$d = Get-Date
Get-Content input.txt -ReadCount 1000 | % {
    $_ | % {
        $_ -replace '^(A\||B\|[^\|]+\||C\|[^\|]+\|[^\|]+\|)(.*)$', '$1P$2'
    } | Add-Content output.txt 
}
(New-TimeSpan $d (Get-Date)).Milliseconds
```

For me this processed 50k rows in 350 milliseconds. You probably get more speed by tweaking the `-ReadCount` value to find the ideal amount.

Comment: Works in theory, but the problem with it is the Join style behaviour of piping the contents from the Foreach-Object pipeine to Set-Content. That will have the consequence that the entire file is held in memory before written to Set-Content. Trying it with a 1 gb file, the powershell just hangs and uses all memory on my computer.

Comment: Looks great, but you might want to make sure the file is initiated/deleted before starting to call Add-Content

Comment: After testing on 1gb file this turns out not to be fast anyway. See my suggestion, now updated (borrowed your regex).

Answer (score 1):

Given the large input file, i would not use either ReadAllText or Get-Content.
They actually read the entire file into memory.

Consider using something along the lines of

```
$filename = ".\input2.csv"
$outfilename = ".\output2.csv"

function ProcessFile($inputfilename, $outputfilename)
{
    $reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText($inputfilename)
    $writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter $outputfilename
    $record = $reader.ReadLine()
    while ($record -ne $null)
    {
        $writer.WriteLine(($record -replace '^(A\||B\|[^\|]+\||C\|[^\|]+\|[^\|]+\|)(.*)$', '$1P$2'))
        $record = $reader.ReadLine()
    }

    $reader.Close()
    $reader.Dispose()
    $writer.Close()
    $writer.Dispose()
}    

ProcessFile $filename $outfilename
```

EDIT: After testing all the suggestions on this page, i have borrowed the regex from Dave Sexton and this is the fastest implementation. Processes a 1gb+ file in 175 seconds. All other implementations are significantly slower on large input files.