# How to delete strings from one file if they exactly mach strings from second file?

Tags: powershell

I have two text files. A `Bigfile.txt` and a `SmallFile.txt`

BigFile.txt sample:
TEXT1
TEXT2
TEXT3
TEXT4

SmallFile.txt sample:
TEXT2
TEXT3

What is the most efficient way how to delete all text strings from BigFile that are also included in SmallFile.txt?

BigFile.txt output
TEXT1
TEXT4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could probably use some error checking, but you might try something like this

```
$bigfile = Get-Content C:\temp\BigFile.txt
$smallfile = Get-Content C:\temp\SmallFile.txt
$difference = Compare-Object $bigfile $smallfile | % {$_.inputobject}
$difference | Set-Content c:\temp\NewBigFile.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for your code. There is a problem. When SmallFile.txt contains strings that are not included in BigFile.txt it will add those strings into a BigFile.

Comment: `get-help compare-object`

Answer (score 1):

```
$BigFile = Get-Content -Path BigFile.txt
$BigFile | ? { $_ -notin (Get-Content -Path SmallFile.txt) }
```

When you've tested and confirmed results are ok:

```
$BigFile = Get-Content -Path BigFile.txt
$BigFile | ? { $_ -notin (Get-Content -Path SmallFile.txt) } | Out-File -FilePath D:\BigFile.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It looks like your code is working.The only problem is that when a big file has 10 000 rows and a small file has 1000 it takes a lot of time to run. It is working fine for 3000 rows big file and 5 rows small file. Any ides how to make it run more efficiently?

Comment: Correct, this is not be the most efficient method. For large files in particular, you would need more complex code that uses .Net methods. See this question for alternatives which are better suited to large files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33072870/how-to-modify-contents-of-a-pipe-delimited-text-file-with-powershell